# Difficult theorem to prove.

Tags: proof-explanation

My professor said that $P=NP$. I believe him, but am struggling to prove this to be true. I have been staring at this equation for hours, and at this point am completely befuddled. Someone please help.
My professor also said anyone who proves it will get extra-credit. The Lord knows I could use some.

Comment: This is a joke right?

Comment: @Seeker no?????

Comment: lol thats hilarious you got a legendary professor

Comment: @DavidRaveh What is happening

Comment: This is an open problem. It’s even one of the [millennium problems](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_Prize_Problems).

Comment: Basically, no extra credit in this class lmao

Comment: @Seeker Wow so I’ve just been trolled by the prof. Thanks bud you’ve saved me a lot of work tonight. Go flames go

Comment: @DavidRaveh yea professor draisaitl isn’t the nicest guy. Shoulda known it was a prank

Comment: If you like, you can troll back and write that if $N=1$, $P=NP$ follows identically

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're professor is just joking around. If you want to joke back, you can let $P=0$ and let $N$ be any number you want.

Comment: Preciate it Accelerator davidraveh seeker. Y’all r life savers. Live long and prosper alhamdullilah amen